# 2 table join and 1 group concat

Tags: mysql, join

I have tables as below

sales

```
salesid    |custid    |date_created    |total_price
S0001       C0001      2015-12-31       20.00
S0002       C0002      2016-01-01       10.00
S0003       C0003      2016-01-02       30.00
S0004       C0001      2016-01-05       50.00
```

salesdetails

```
salesdetailsid    |salesid    |product_name           |quantity
D0001              S0001       pencil                  3
D0002              S0001       book                    2
D0003              S0001       ruler                   1
D0004              S0002       Hard Cover File Folder  1
D0005              S0003       A4 Paper                1
D0006              S0003       Notebook                1
D0006              S0004       Mouse                   1
```

My expected output should be:

if custid is C0001, output:

```
salesid    | Purchase Date    | Items
S0001        2015-12-31         pencil x 3,book x 2, ruler x 1
S0004        2016-01-05         Mouse x 1
```

if custid is C0002, output:

```
salesid    | Purchase Date    | Items
S0002        2016-01-01         Hard Cover File Folder x 1
```

if custid is C0003, output:

```
salesid    | Purchase Date    | Items
S0003        2016-01-02         A4 Paper x 1, Notebook x 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT s.salesid          AS "id", 
       s.time_created     AS "Purchase Date",   
       s.total_price      AS "Amount", 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Concat(prodname, ' x ', quantity) SEPARATOR ', ') AS "Items" 
FROM   sales s 
JOIN   salesdetails d 
  ON   s.salesid = d.salesid 
WHERE  s.custid = 'C0001'
```

Comment: Show us data sample and expected output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Hi, I have edited my question, hope it gives a clear picture.

Comment: That is better, so what result do you have with current query and what is wrong?

Comment: the error is say C0001 has 2 sales, it showing "Column "S.SALESID" must be in the GROUP BY list", C0002 showed the desire output, and if I use a new customer C0123 which dont have a sales yet, it shows the sales table last row of data which is `S0004,2016-01-05,null` result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your GROUP BY clause, which in effect makes your group_concat work, see if this works:

```
SELECT s.salesid          AS "id", 
       s.time_created     AS "Purchase Date",   
       s.total_price      AS "Amount", 
       Group_concat(Concat(prodname, ' x ', quantity) SEPARATOR ', ') AS "Items" 
FROM   sales s 
JOIN   salesdetails d 
ON     s.salesid = d.salesid 
WHERE  s.custid = 'C0001' 
GROUP BY s.salesid
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much for pointing out my mistake! small mistake, big headache... problem finally solved, its 2.30am here. I need some rest. Once again, thank you!!